# SPFX 404 When Trying to Get Current User In Workbench

Tags: web-part, spfx, pnp, react-webpart

I'm trying to get the user context in my React web part and I am getting 404's when requesting: `https://localhost:4321/_api/web/currentuser`

This is the part of the code that fetches the current user:

```
private GetUserProperties(): void {
/*
pnp.setup({
  spfxContext: this.context
});
 */

pnp.sp.web.currentUser.get().then((r: CurrentUser) => {
  console.log('CURRENT USER', r);
});
}
```

This was setup as a SharePoint online application. I've tried several different solutions with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get user details through local machine. The API you are using is a SharePoint REST API and for that you will need a SharePoint site and access to the site to get the current user details by using the following URL:

> https://Your_SharePoint_Site_Url/_api/web/currentuser

Answer (score 0):

You commented out the bit you needed. You need to run the setup with the context.

```
private GetUserProperties(): void {
  pnp.setup({
    spfxContext: this.context
  });
  pnp.sp.web.currentUser.get().then((r: CurrentUser) => {
    console.log('CURRENT USER', r);
});
```